# FILE/IO QUESTION: Bug in my software ifstream does not extract integers from input file into variables in my software

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream

**Summarize the Problem**

I am creating a console application that calculates a dates value based on the starting date 1900 jan 1st and adds all the days between those two dates. In the problem/my program, I have to use File/IO. Demonstrated in my software below, I attempt to extract integers. However, nothing shows in my output file. When I debug, none of the integers get extracted from input the file. I am unsure of how to fix this problem since i've tried many solutions. (WRITING TO OUTPUT FILE IS FINE, CHOICE 1 WORKS GREAT, CHOICE 2 NOT SO MUCH).

**Describe what you've tried**

1. Changing location of input file (file open correctly in working directory of cpp file)
2. Switching the file i/o operations to outside of the do while loop (still fails to work)
3. Check if file is open, check if it's correctly working, and check if iostream flags are good, bad, fail etc.
4. Multiple code-rewrites.

---

**THE CODE IN QUESTION**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include"dayValue.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    dayValue newDay;
    int day = 0, year = 0, month = 0;
    int choice = 0;
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    inFile.open("dateInput.txt"); //Broken and trying to fix. Not too sure what issue is.
    if (inFile.fail())            //is it ok?
    { 
        cout<<"Input file did not open please check it\n";
        return 1;
    }
    outFile.open("dateOutput.txt");
    if (outFile.fail())            //is it ok?
    { 
        cout<<"output file did not open please check it\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    cout << "Hi! This is Adam's day calculator program.\n";
    cout << "Would you like to input your own date into the console or read dates from a file? \nType 1 to input a date or 2 to access your files: ";
    do
    {
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Welcome to the day calculator program, can you please input a date for us to store\n";
            cout << "Please input the month: ";
            cin >> month;
            cout << "Please input the day: ";
            cin >> day;
            cout << "Please input the year: ";
            cin >> year;
            newDay.setDate(year, month, day);
            newDay.print();
            outFile << "Your date: " << newDay.month << "/" << newDay.day << "/" << newDay.year << " is the weekday " << newDay.findWeekDay() << " and has a day value of " << newDay.findDayValue() << " (current day is inclusive) "; 
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            // newDay.setDate(year, month, day);
            inFile >> year >> month >> day;
            newDay.setDate(year, month, day);

            // do the loop while there are still numbers in the file
            while (inFile >> year >> month >> day)
            {
                outFile << "Your date: " << newDay.month << "/" << newDay.day << "/" << newDay.year << " is the weekday " << newDay.findWeekDay() << " and has a day value of " << newDay.findDayValue() << " (current day is inclusive) ";
                newDay.setDate(year, month, day);
                inFile >> year >> month >> day;
            }
        }
    } while(choice < 1 || choice > 2);
  
    cout << "\n Thanks for using the day calculator application\n (Check your output file for write)";
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Picture of file location

[image]

Picture of actual text file in question

[image]

EDIT 1: Attaching image of debugger right after the first `inFile >> year >> month >> day;`

[image: Confusing Debug]

Comment: your loop has an extra `inFile >> year >> month >>day`. Hence, all other issues aside, you would see only every second line of the input in the output. Did you try to add some `cout`s or use a debugger to see if the input file is read correctly before you write it to the output file?

Comment: Delete `inFile >> year >> month >> day;` after `newDay.setDate(year, month, day);`

Comment: Choice 2 is where the problem lies. Hi, I have used a debugger, and set breakpoints. What I dont understand is that inFile does not extract anything. File is not being read correctly. Its null terminated maybe? it stops before the file can even be read. Do you think this is an error with my drive/system?

Comment: @dresherjm tried this and still no output.

Comment: Maybe you debugged too late meaning after you read all of the data in the file. Also you won't get any output unless you enter the while loop. After you execute choice 2 the file should be at the end. Meaning executing it a second time the program should print nothing.

Comment: I have attached an image of debugger for clarification if I am doing anything wrong. The issue seems to be that the file is not being read properly to input the data. I'm not sure how/why the program won't input the numbers in my input file to the variables themselves.

Comment: My expectation is the file is empty when you are debugging at choice 2. You may want to replace `inFile >> year >> month >> day;  newDay.setDate(year, month, day);` with `if (inFile >> year >> month >> day) { newDay.setDate(year, month, day); } else { // print error message and exit}`

Answer (score 0):

There 3 lines (##52, 56, 60), where input data is being read:

```cpp
inFile >> year >> month >> day;
```

However, there is only 1 line (#58), where data is written

```cpp
outFile << "Your date: " << newDay.month << "/" << newDay.day << "/" << newDay.year << " is the weekday " << newDay.findWeekDay() << " and has a day value of " << newDay.findDayValue() << " (current day is inclusive) ";
```

Therefore not all numbers from the input file are being saved in the output file.
Please, fix it and try again.

Regards,
Dmitry

Comment: `dateInput.txt` and `dateOutput.txt` are 2 different files.

Comment: Hi, if (inFile >> year >> month >> day) { newDay.setDate(year, month, day); } else { // print error message and exit} returns the error message. So I know it's a problem with the file. But there is clearly data inside the file so im more confused then when I started haha

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).